# import Azure HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration comes Error: cannot import name 'HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration'

Tags: azure, vector, importerror, azure-cognitive-search, hnswlib

Here is the reference document I follow with:
https://esteininger.medium.com/building-a-vector-search-engine-using-hnsw-and-cosine-similarity-753fb5268839
&
https://github.com/Azure/cognitive-search-vector-pr/blob/main/demo-python/code/azure-search-vector-python-sample.ipynb

```
from azure.search.documents.models import Vector
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (  
    SearchIndex,  
    SearchField,  
    SearchFieldDataType,  
    SimpleField,  
    SearchableField,  
    SearchIndex,  
    SemanticConfiguration,  
    PrioritizedFields,  
    SemanticField,  
    SearchField,  
    SemanticSettings,  
    VectorSearch, 
    HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration 
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3ZWN.png)

At first, I faced import error which is about import Vector. I saw its solution on stackoverflow by updating azure.search.documents to the version ==11.4.0b6; While HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration would be alwasy error no matter which version I used. I've tried azure.search.documents 11.4.0b6 and 11.4.0b4

If the import error remain unsolved, the folling part would be error too.

```
vector_search = VectorSearch(

    algorithm_configurations=[

        HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration(

            name="my-vector-config",

            kind="hnsw",

            parameters={

                "m": 4,

                "efConstruction": 400,
                "efSearch": 500,
                "metric": "cosine"
            }
        )
    ]
)
```

I also tried to walkaround by `import hnswlib`, but it didn't work...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7ij4.png)

If someone has conquer this issue, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Visual C++ Build tools are required to install hnswlib, have tried to install these requirements before installing hnswlib? what error it's showing after that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Azure Cognitive Search’s Vector feature you don’t have to install hnswlib separately.

Can you ensure you’re using the latest azure-search-documents pip package?

Try `pip install azure-search-documents --pre --upgrade`.

The latest Python SDK pre-release version that includes Vector search capabilities can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/azure-search-documents/11.4.0b8/

Comment: Funnily, the latest (at the current moment) preview version 11.4.0b11 does not include `Vector`

Comment: correct, it is no longer needed. instead, you should do: 
 import from azure.search.documents.models import (
    RawVectorQuery,
    VectorizableTextQuery,
)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Farzzy's helpful answer:

I had the same issue, For me just running
`pip install azure-search-documents --pre --upgrade`
didn't fix it, so I also ran the following commands:

```
pip install azure-search --pre --upgrade
```

```
pip install azure-core --pre --upgrade
```

And one of them fixed that.

Comment: none worked for me... keep getting the can't import Vector

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the suggested answers worked for me but I ended up finding another solution in Azure Samples. Hope this helps...

repo:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-comparison-tool

I imported **HnswParameters** and **VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration** from *azure.search.documents.indexes.models* instead of **HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration**:

```
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (
    HnswParameters,
    PrioritizedFields,
    SearchableField,
    SearchField,
    SearchFieldDataType,
    SearchIndex,
    SemanticConfiguration,
    SemanticField,
    SemanticSettings,
    SimpleField,
    VectorSearch,
    VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration,
)
```

Then I changed my vector search configuration to:

```
vector_search = VectorSearch(
    algorithm_configurations=[
        VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration(
            name="natp-vector-config",
            kind="hnsw",
            hnsw_parameters=HnswParameters(m=4, ef_construction=400, ef_search=500, metric="cosine")
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing 11.4.0b8  `pip install azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8`.

Comment: 11.4.0b8 still gives me an issue... cannot import name 'HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models